# Pass PHP processing to another page

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Think of it as a poor mans template system. I want to store my values into a data array and then continue processing the view on another page. What PHP command would I use to accommodate this?

Comment: Store the values in the session and redirect to the next page. Or include the next page and exit the current page.

Comment: Could u plz explain better what you are trying to accomplish?! You can store a PHP array in a PHP arrfile.php and simply include('arrfile.php') from all your pages.

Comment: @Marco Demaio: this is really a bad idea. What happens if there are multiple requests coming, and they include/overwrite `arrfile.php`?

Comment: @Yorirou: overwrite what, a request can't overwrite the arrfile.php. The file contains the array with all the data he needs, he wrote those data down by his hands, so his pages are including the arrfile.php (or call it config.php) and they can all see the data. Unless I did not understood what he wants to do, that's why I asked to explain better.

Comment: Do you mean you want to fill out a form and then have that data passed to another page?

Answer (score 1):

You can `include` the second file and the second file will have access to all data.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set your array, and then include the page that will display it. Your included page will have access to the value(s) of $myArray.

**Main Page**

```
<?php
    $myArray= Array(1, 2, 3);
    include('ArrayDisplayPage.php');
?>
```

**ArrayDisplayPage.php**

```
<?php
    var_dump($myArray);
?>
```